# How to simplify 4 nested IF functions in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

This might be a simple fix I'm unsure. I have the following formula which I would like to be able to drag up and down `=IF(C311>B311,IF(C310>B310,IF(B309>C309,IF(C312>B312,2,1),0),0),0)`

I'm guessing AND can be implemented in some way but I'm not sure. The logic behind my goal is if C311>B311 AND C310>B310 AND B309>C309 then check to see if C312>B312 if it is then put a 2 else put a 1. Perhaps there is another solution as well I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `=IF(AND(C311>B311,C310>B310,B309>C309),IF(C312>B312,2,1),"")`

Last argument I left it as `""` but replace it to whatever you need.

Comment: I am going to guess that the "" should be a 1, but that will be up to the OP to decide.  Though according to their original formula it looks like it should be a 0

Comment: Yeah, I followed to logic in the second paragraph. Wouldn't trust the original formula.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach-

```
=IF((C311>B311)*(C310>B310)*(B309>C309),IF(C312>B312,2,1),"")
```

Comment: Interesting! what's the proper documentation or nomenclature for using the '*' in (C311>B311)*(C310>B310)*(B309>C309). Is it the same as an AND?

Comment: @guanciale The logical test in an if statement needs to evaluate to either true of false.  (Aside: When True or False get evaluate in a math operation they are evaluated as True =1 and False=0).  Based on that, anything multiplied by 0 is zero, so multiplication is acting like AND and converter the comparison operation to 0 or 1.   You can extend out the logic if you take 0 as false and anything else as True.  Following that line of thought, + acts like OR.

Comment: @guanciale Basically `*` is doing logical `AND` operation based on `Boolean` logic and return 0 or 1 means TRUE or FALSE.